# design pattern which can avoid if else condition to take decision about major functionality in .net

Tags: .net

Example:

```
isSettingEnabled == true

    //call mathod1

else

    //call method 2
```

the disadvantage of this, in my project, is that the flow can be easily known to someone because of the if else.

Please let me know if this problem can be solved by some design pattern.

Comment: _"the flow can be easily known to someone because of the if else"_ - what? Do you intentionally want to decrease the readability of your source code? There is a pattern for that, it's called [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to thwart people cracking your app, or something else?

Comment: sorry for replying late. .yes..we are trying to reduce the readability, the person who is analysing thec code should not know that there are two different flows. there will be a key in data base which decides the execution flow. i want some pattern where i can avoid if else condition

Answer (score -1):

> When you find yourself dealing for instance with user input and/or
>   server events and see lots of branching in your code (if/switch
>   statements) on some  _state  variables, chances are high that a state
>   machine could be introduced to simplify things.

Try State Machine: [Stateless](https://github.com/AdaptiveConsulting/RfqStateMachine) or [asynchronous, based on Stateless](https://github.com/prasannavl/LiquidState).

Comment: OP's question is not clear, so you can't just randomly name some design patterns in an answer without explaining how those patterns answer OP's question.

Comment: i wil go through the patterns you have suggested. Thank you